# scrollview into gridlayout cell: how to prevent it to grow vertically?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to achieve a layout with a scrollview and a fixed bottombar. The bottombar has a fixed height, and the scrollview should take the remaining height of the screen but should never grow whatever its content's height (as it should scroll the content).

I've tryed lots of layout combinations, but i'm unable to find the correct one.

If i use a LinearLayout and the layout_weight trick, the problem is the same.

In the example below: change the android:minHeight="600dp" in the linearlayout to 300dp, and it will work ok. In this example, why is the scrollview growing so much in height ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:rowCount="2"
android:background="#fff"
android:columnCount="1"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/zoneContent"
    android:background="#00f"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#f00"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minHeight="600dp" />
</ScrollView>
<GridLayout
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|fill_vertical"
    android:background="#0f0"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:layout_row="1" />
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to do the trick

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/zoneContent"
    android:background="#00f"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#f00"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minHeight="300dp" />
</ScrollView>
<GridLayout
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|fill_vertical"
    android:background="#0f0"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:layout_row="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the LinearLayout as a parent layout instead of GridLayout, and then fix the weight of the layouts.